# use 'XMLHttpRequest' to get external website's source - Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

is there any method to get external website's source with javascript and without use of jquery?

this code can't get external page source:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'internal_page_only:(.html', true);
request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    alert(request.responseText);
  } else { //error }};
request.onerror = function() { //error }; 
request.send();
```

Comment: You can't make a cross-origin request to a webpage that doesn't let you do that. Read more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: The external website MUST generate a CORS header that allows your website to load it. Otherwise XMLHttpRequest will always fail and generate a Cross-Origin error. This is by design. So if the external website already generate the correct CORS headers then you can do it. If not you need to talk to the owners. If that's not possible you need to fetch the page from your server

Comment: You must enable `CORS header` on other host to able to get it remotely.

Comment: but is there  a method with yahooapis? (in javascript only not jquery)